# How to directly show print page using FPDF PHP code?

Tags: php, fpdf

I am working on generating the bill for a customer and I using FPDF and PHP for generating the bill. Here I don't want to use execute `"application/pdf"`. Here I want to directly print in print screen without using PDF. How to convert FPDF PHP code to directly print the bill. As the image shows.

[image]

Comment: You can use directly browser print functionality.

Comment: I am going via pdf page then print page. but I want to directly get the print page.

Comment: I changed fpdf code from application/pdf to text/html.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also use correct Markdown formatting (`![description][url]`) for your image please.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id='DivIdToPrint'>
    <p>This is a sample text for printing purpose.</p>
</div>
<p>Do not print.</p>
<input type='button' id='btn' value='Print' onclick='printDiv();'>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function printDiv() 
{

  var divToPrint=document.getElementById('DivIdToPrint');

  var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');

  newWin.document.open();

  newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body></html>');

  newWin.document.close();

  setTimeout(function(){newWin.close();},10);

}
```

Comment: is this code is fixed, means if I Pass 3 values as first name, middle name, last name that will print correctly but if I pass only 2 values as the first name and last name then the result give us positions change.